# Editing .bash_profiles with conda installed

Tags: bash, macos, conda

I am trying to follow along with a book that for some of the chapters requires the line

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/scripts"
```

be added to a `.bash_profiles` in the home directory. Probably, after peaking later in the book it is to launch scripts located in that folder quickly from the terminal without specification of path of that file, it seems useful so I would like to do it.

Although, since I have previously installed `conda` on my mac, it apparently changed something and addition of that line did not alter the output of `echo $PATH`

`.bash_profiles` looks now like this:

```
# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/eshauchuk/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/eshauchuk/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/eshauchuk/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
        \export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/scripts"
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/eshauchuk/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/scripts" 
# <<< conda init <<<
```

I have added the mentioned line to the near end of the `.bash_profile` now and also went to the found in this files conda files to try add it there with no change for now.

What can I do to make it work

Answer (score 3):

Check this comment:

```
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
```

So try to put your line after the block like this:

```
# <<< conda init <<<
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/scripts"
```

Comment: Thank you, I have moved the line but after the of the terminal the `echo $PATH` still does not show the change in bash set

Comment: Maybe try .bashrc insted

Comment: I don't have such file in my Home directory and after looking for it with ` ls -l ./*/* | grep ".bash" ` have still no result. Thank you for the effort to help, I feel I can try later to go around this on the machine without conda installed.